# Text not getting rendered for an object

Tags: react-native

I have this below code, The alert shows following message:

```
{"item":{"isPositive":"false", "balance":"-500","currency":"AUD"}}
```

If I do alert on "ob" I get undefined. My problem is that the Text doesn't display anything:

```js
_renderItemView(item) {
  const ob = item
    //alert(JSON.stringify(ob))
    alert(JSON.stringify(item))
  return(<>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.iconContainer}></View>

          <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.subText}>{item.date}asasas</Text>
              {/* <Text style={styles.transactionDescText}>{item.description}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.subText}>{item.descFrom}</Text> */}
          </View>

          <View style={styles.balanceContainer}>
              {/* <Text style={styles.balance}>{item.currency}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.balanceSubText}>{item.balance}</Text> */}
          </View>
      </View>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: can you create a small repro in expo?

Answer (score 0):

I was using renderItem={(item, index) => _renderItemView(item) to render
I needed an extra brace like this

renderItem={({item, index}) =>